# Multiple photos in discord.py embed

Tags: python-3.x, embed, discord.py

Okey, I've got two charts images and  I want to send them in one embed message:
Here's the code I wrote:

```
 charts = [
            discord.File("/root/discord.py/chart-render/tempchart.png", filename="tempchart.png"),
            discord.File("/root/discord.py/chart-render/ramchart.png", filename="ramchart.png")
            ]
            stats.set_image(url="attachment://tempchart.png")
            stats.set_image(url="attachment://ramchart.png")
            await ctx.send(embed=stats, files=charts)
```

the problem is that the one is sending in embed, but the second one doesn't - it's sending over the embed message

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have linked an image I hope can help you to understand how embeds work a bit better, so essentially embeds can only have 1 image per one and you will need to send two embeds, unfortunately. Also, [here](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) is a nice online embed visualizer.

I hope this helped

[image]

Comment: Okey, so I'll send two embeds

Answer (score 1):

So basically to simplify `@Ethan M-H`'s answer.
This is how to send 3 images in one embed in discord.py
https://discord.com/channels/336642139381301249/381965515721146390/739465676586221628

```py
embedVar = discord.Embed(title=f'title', description=f'description', color=0xffd800)
embedVar.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/84319995256905728/252292324967710721/embed.png")    #the image itself
embedVar.set_footer(text='footer',icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/84319995256905728/252292324967710721/embed.png")   #image in icon_url
embedVar.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/84319995256905728/252292324967710721/embed.png") #image itself
```

Consider reading this: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed :) and also consider joining the official discord.py server to ask more questions https://discord.gg/dpy (since you code discord you should have a discord account :))

Hope I have provided a **great** answer. Have fun coding!

*I am new to stack overflow and the answers here are based on https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed, and have not been tested yet. Please comment on what things I need to correct.*
Also, there is no need to post two embeds unless you need two BIG images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest code that can do the same.

```py
embed1 = discord.Embed(url="https://rajtech.me")
embed2 = discord.Embed(url="https://rajtech.me")

embed1.set_image(url='image1')
embed2.set_image(url="image2")

await ctx.send(embeds=[embed1, embed2])
```

The only thing that needs to be common between the two embeds are the url, here it is `rajtech.me`.
If you want to add stuff like title, add it to the first embed.

[Image of how it looks like on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Akgc.png)

**Note: On mobile phones, the 2nd image will simply not be shown.**